# How can I pass an object into a global array with a public function call using 'this'?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have a ToDo class that has a description, date, and priority as private member variables.

I am attempting to take the filled ToDo and add that into a global array of ToDos.

I've set all the member variables of the object using this->description, this->date, and this->priority, but when I attempt to add the object using the following - TODO_GLOBAL_ARRAY[CURRENT_LOC_OF_ARRAY] = this; - I receive an error stating "no viable overloaded '='".

I've also tried to instantiate an instance of the ToDo object and pass that along to the array, but that still leaves the original object without the data and does not print out correctly.

```
//ToDo Header


#include <string>

using std::string;

#ifndef TODOLIST
#define TODOLIST

class ToDoList{
private:
    string description;
    string date;
    int priority;

public:
    bool addToList(ToDoList todoItem);
    bool addToList(string desc, string date, int priority);
    bool getNextItem(ToDoList &toDoItem);
    bool getNextItem(string &desc, string &date, int &priority);
    bool getByPriority(ToDoList *results, int priority);
    bool getByPriority(ToDoList *results, int priority, int &resultSize);
    void printToDo();
    void printToDo(ToDoList aToDo);
    void printToDoList(ToDoList *aToDoList);
    void printToDoList(ToDoList *aToDoList, int size);

    ToDoList();
    ToDoList(string desc, string date, int priority);
// TODO: implement method to get ToDo from usr input
};

#endif

extern ToDoList usr_TODO_list[];
extern const int MAX_ITEMS_TODO;
extern int SIZE_OF_USR_LIST;
extern int NEXT_INDEX;

// From ToDo.cpp

bool ToDoList::addToList(string desc, string date, int priority){
    if (SIZE_OF_USR_LIST == MAX_ITEMS_TODO) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        ToDoList aToDo;
        this->description = desc;
        this->date = date;
        this->priority = priority;
        usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST] = this;
        SIZE_OF_USR_LIST++;
        return true;
    }
}

// From main.cpp

using namespace std;

ToDoList usr_TODO_list[100];
int const MAX_ITEMS_TODO (100);
int SIZE_OF_USR_LIST = 0;
int NEXT_INDEX = 0;

int main()
{ // etc...
```

Expected: to pass the object into the array using 'this'

Actual: No viable overloaded '=' error

Comment: Some of the naming here is a bit confusing, `ToDoList` is infact an array element as opposed to a list. I'd try to refactor your code a bit to make it clearer. Anyway if you want to add a copy the you should use `usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST] = *this;` so you're not trying to assign a pointer. If you're actually trying to store pointers then you probably want to declare your array as `ToDoList *usr_TODO_list[100];`.

Comment: This architecture is just bizzare, but your else-clause should be reducible to just `usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST++] = ToDoList(desc, date, priority); return true;` And note that `aToDo` in your implementation is pointless. Not sure what you wanted it for. Regardless, your code is seems brazenly confusing a ToDo *list* with a ToDo *item*. The former should hold instances of the latter, and as near as I can see, the latter need only be a description, date, and priority simple object.

Comment: @George Thank you!!! I forgot that this is a pointer. I used the deference operator and it worked. Can you post that as a response so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST] = this;` is trying to assign a pointer to a `class` object. In this case, since `ToDoList` is trivially copyable, you can just dereference `this`.

`usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST] = *this;`

I'd also consider refactoring a little to make things a bit less confusing i.e. `ToDoList` -> `ToDo` or if something else makes more contextual sense like `Job` then that could work too. And as @WhozCraig pointed out `addToList` could be reduced to :

```
bool ToDoList::addToList(string desc, string date, int priority) {
    if (SIZE_OF_USR_LIST == MAX_ITEMS_TODO) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST++] = ToDoList(desc, date, priority);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Although this would mean that the `this` object is unaffected, if it needs to be mutated you could instead use :

```
bool ToDoList::addToList(string desc, string date, int priority) {
    if (SIZE_OF_USR_LIST == MAX_ITEMS_TODO) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        *this = ToDoList(desc, date, priority);
        usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST++] = *this;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use for example:

```
{
    auto& nextListElem = usr_TODO_list[SIZE_OF_USR_LIST];
    nextListElem.description = desc;
    nextListElem.date = date;
    nextListElem.priority = priority;
    SIZE_OF_USR_LIST++;
    return true;
}
```